# Read child node list in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase, Lets say I have a DatabaseReference of a node which has 10 child nodes. Is there any way to get the child list from the DatabaseReference or from any Query. How can I simply read data without using Listener events in android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a singleton which has child update listeners implemented, and stores an array of the child nodes, independent to the UI. That way, on load, you'll get the child nodes as soon as possible from that singleton's array.